# Calling CSJS from within SSJS in XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages

I'm currently working on rewriting a function from a LotusScript script library in JavaScript. The LotusScript function contains both front end and back end elements -
input boxes are used to gather information from the user - so I'm wondering how best to do this. Is it possible to call a modal dialog window using csjs from within ssjs?

Comment: Tony be careful what you wish for. Dialogboxes are a distinct feature of client application and are rather irritating in web applications, so consider if there are better ways to deal with the UI flow. The OneUI documentation (3.x as of now) has some inspiration

Comment: Thanks, this is unfortunately a legacy application which for the moment at least requires dialog boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have a look at the xe:dialog control. You can show and hide that dialog using SSJS.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm trying this out now.

Answer (score 10):

Here are the SSJS and CSJS commands to show/hide the dialog:

SSJS:

```
var comp = getComponent("serverSideId");
//To Open the dialog
comp.show();
//To close the dialog
comp.hide();
```

CSJS

```
//To Open the dialog
XSP.openDialog("#{id:serverSideId}");
//To close the dialog
XSP.closeDialog("#{id:serverSideId}");
```

And just for fun, SSJS that executes CSJS:

```
//To Open the dialog
facesContext.getViewRoot().postScript("XSP.openDialog('#{id:serverSideId}')");
//To Close the dialog
facesContext.getViewRoot().postScript("XSP.closeDialog('#{id:serverSideId}')");
```

Comment: @TonyGuiheen: If this answer works for you then make sure select this as your answer to help the community.

Comment: yes, this answer has been a big help. I would like to know if there is any way of passing a parameter to the dialog box when opening it, either with CSJS or SSJS.

Comment: @KeithStric showed how to open and close the dialogs in various ways. To pass parameters to the dialog, use a viewScope variable to hold the value and set the property refreshOnShow="true".

Comment: Could you use this to show a dojo standby widget while an xAgent is creating and streaming an excel spreadsheet to the browser? I've had no luck with that particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this?

```
view.postScript("XSP.openDialog('#{id:dialog1}');");
```

Comment: Thanks, I may use that in future.